# Require five example tags for a new proposal to be posted

Tags: feature-request, tags, area-51

If you can't think of five tags a SE site could use, then your proposal will quite likely be closed as "not a real proposal" anyway.

Comment: Unless you don't have a clue about that subject and just try to get badges for proposing it first...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a good idea to start proposal about subject you don't know.

Comment: @HoxLyxVierx: why? if you can't make up five tags to bring some ordering in your proposal there won't be many questions (therefore not requiring ordering, but also being a too small proposal to pass beta). Of course this could be softened into "require at least five tags for entering commitment phase"

Comment: Vote on this comment if you prefer "Require five example tags for a proposal to enter commitment phase"

Answer (score 1):

A good idea, but ...

I worry that creating pre-defined tags so early would affect the example questions people submit, though -- and the example on and off topic questions are *by far* the best way to figure out what a site "is".

Comment: maybe they should remain hidden and only become visible for followers after having posted five example questions. I just think this is some way to help proposers thinking deeper about whether their idea would really create a Q&A site of its own or whether it shouldn't be generalized a bit (or closed as subset)

Comment: I was able to award you the bounty despite a "This bounty ended 25 mins ago", is this a bug or a nice new feature for those like me who forgot to award the bounty in time?

Comment: @tobias there is a tiny grace period but it's simply based on the odds of when your bounty ends versus when the hourly task runs

Comment: thanks, [quoted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68019/can-bounties-be-awarded-after-expiration/68021#68021)