# How to create tags in an area 51 proposal?

Tags: support, tags, area-51

I just have created a new proposal in Area 51.

Now I need to create tags, that I have in mind, but I can not find where could I create them.

How can I create tags for my proposal?

Comment: You don't create *sites* there, only *proposals*. After long process, such a proposal can become a site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Area 51 proposals simply have no tags. It's not part of the system. You only define what the site should be about, and let people post example questions.

As Jeff explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67944/152859):

> I worry that creating pre-defined tags so early would affect the example questions people submit, though -- and the example on and off topic questions are by far the best way to figure out what a site "is".

And Robert also says [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14751/46868):

> Area 51 is not a "subject of expertise" and this is not set up like a generalized Q&A site. That's the basics of it.

Comment: I see. But it will be hard to start the site (or proposal) if people do not properly understand the idea behind the proposal. For example, I have create a proposal of politics, in POrtuguese. So, in my understand, we should divide in 2 groups of tags. Location and theme. Location should be Federal or State or municipality. And group of themes should be lets say public health, as example. Now there one could say that hospital 1 is not open at saturday, what could be the issue and what could we do to make it works. If I leave open tags since the begining people will not understand theBasicConcep

Comment: Not sure about that. Just write a clear description and it should be enough. You can get better help by posting in the [Discussion Zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/), people there are much more familiar with Area 51 than the people here.

Comment: Continuing: State - tags of all state names. Municipality - tags of all municipality names of the country. Users could create later, a lower level, tlets say, neighborhood. Themes could be, big themes like Public Health, Public Tratsportation system. And users could, or should create the lower (specific) level tags. I think this aproach can cause a limitation of the proccess to create new SITES or proposal.

Comment: ok I will create a new proposition about the hability to create tags since the begining there. Thanks

Comment: You have to remember that the community builds the site not you.