# I did not receive my bounty even when I reached the requirements

Tags: support, bounties

On this question: [Dart to WASM compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230563/dart-to-wasm-compilation/76305863#76305863) ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76305863/timeline)), I did everything according to the guidelines and still did not get my bounty.

Comment: It was awarded few seconds ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Bounty grace period ends in 5 hours.

That means the bounty poster still has 5 hours to decide which answer to award the bounty to. If they don't, you'll get half the bounty amount since your answer qualifies for automatic awarding as described in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

[image: screenshot of bounty banner during grace period]

---

> Bounty grace period has ended.

Even when the period has ended, there's still a batch job that needs to run in order to award the bounty; it's not instantaneous, just like with (almost all) badges.

[image: screenshot of bounty banner after grace period]

Comment: Actually I did the wrong so question. Let me update it. It was the other question with +200 bounty.

Comment: Thank you. So it's more like a batch job instead of an event trigger that gives me bounty?

Comment: If the author awards it, it's instantaneous. If not, there's a batch job (no idea how often it runs, perhaps once an hour).

Comment: In 2010 it was hourly based on info from the master himself: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63610/require-five-example-tags-for-a-new-proposal-to-be-posted/67944#comment163354_67944

Comment: @Glorfindel yeah, since grace period ending it was little more than one hour until it was really done. Can be improved with something like "Grace period ended, please wait for the bounty to be completed".